# Create bounding box for multiple points on Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, spatial, geography

I have a table with multiple points and I need to create a bounding box that contains all of them. I've tried to use de function SDO_GEOM.SDO_MBR wich is supposed to create a minimum bounding rectangle but it seems to do it individually for all of my points. Here is what my sql query looks like:

```
SELECT SDO_GEOM.SDO_MBR(T2.GEOMETRY)
FROM TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2
ON T2.ID_ID=T1.ID
WHERE T1.ID_CLIENT=123456
AND T1.TYPE='ABC')
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found what i was looking for. I used SDO_AGGR_MBR instead of SDO_GEOM.SDO_MBR...